# Dismissing a modal view controller to view other than its parent view

Tags: objective-c, ios, modal-dialog

In my application, I present a modal view with a navigation controller. After going through several screens in the navigation, I dismiss the view by simply using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Which exits the view gracefully with a top-down transition. But it goes to the initial view, and I would like it to go back to the root of the navigation controller using the same top-down modal transition. Is there a neat way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean the root view of the navigation controller _inside_ the modal?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: transitions inside navigation controller are implemented with animations to left or right, not top-down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go to the root use the following

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But this will not show you the top down animation, in order to achieve that you will need to do some custom modification, it is possible that you will need to create your onw UINavigationController

Comment: I suppose this will do, I might make a custom object later on. Thank you!

Comment: i made one in the past, if you want you can follow my github(its empty now :S) but i will update it soon here is the link https://github.com/Infusion-apps

Answer (score 0):

if you want to switch that.

```
 yourclassName *obj=[[yourclassName alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourclassName" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```